# CRM 2011 SDK Read Solution zip file

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any object/class in CRM 2011 SDK to which I can feed the customizations zip file and then I can simply use its properties/methods to read/validate the contents of the customizations zip file before importing?

The only relevant object I was able to find was ImportSolutionRequest. But it only takes the customizations zip file as a byte[] using the CustomizationFile property exposed on it. But it doesnt let me read the contents of the file. Too bad :(

Also, if there is any other way to achieve the same I am open for it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on looking at the contents of a customizations.zip file, it should be possible to use the [System.IO.Packaging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) namespace to unpack the zip and then read the inner customizations.xml into an XML document.